# Bounding error for non-alternating Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Given a function whose Taylor Series Expansion is ${\textit not}$ an alternating series, such as $f(x)=e^x$,  my understanding is that bounding the error term  $E_{n+1}$ is not good enough to ensure accuracy. How do I bound the error so that I can approximate $f(x)=e^x$ say, up to 5 decimal places? Thanks.

Comment: If you have an alternating series, then your error will always be less than the next term in the series.

If your series does not alternate.  I am going to point you here for some explicit formula for the remainder
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder

Comment: Thank you, I was mixing the next term in the series with the Lagrange form of the remainder.